# JQuery reverse each() with find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this kind of question has been asked before, but the general solution of

```
$($("input").get().reverse()).each(function() { /* ... */ });
```

is not working for me. I have an xml document that contains a list of concerts that I'd like to display on a webpage. So, in JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "concerts.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: false,
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('concert').each(function() {
            /*do stuff*/
        });
    }
});
```

However, I'd like to display the concerts in reverse order. So, I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "concerts.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: false,
    success: function(xml) {
        $($(xml).find('concert').reverse()).each(function() {
            /*do stuff*/
        });
    }
});
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try doing whatever you do in reverse order. For example, instead of `appendChild`, use `insertBefore(0, item)`.

Comment: To clarify the above, the call should be: `$($(xml).find('concert').get().reverse()).each(function() { /* ... */ });`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You excluded the call to the [`get()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method.

```
   // --------------------v
$($(xml).find('concert').get().reverse()).each(function() {
```

This is needed to get an Array of the elements from the jQuery object. This is what allows you to call `.reverse()`, which is on `Array.prototype`.

Comment: Thanks; all is well now. I thought `.find('concert')` gave me the array that I needed; I didn't know `get()` was required.

Answer (score 3):

To walk through the items in reverse order, why not just use code like this:

```
var data = $("input");
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var item = data[i];
    // do whatever you want to do with item here
}
```

Or, if you want to make a function out of it that takes a jQuery object and your function:

```
function reverseEach(jQueryObj, fn) {
    for (var i = jQueryObj.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (fn.call(jQueryObj[i], i, jQueryObj[i]) === false) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So, you could then call:

```
reverseEach($(xml).find('concert'), function() {
    // do stuff here
});
```

or:

```
reverseEach($("input"), function() {
    // do stuff here
});
```

Or, you could even make reverseEach a jQuery plugin if you wanted.

Comment: Yay for a non-jquery answer (`for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {}`).